# Huawei Push Kit Error : 907135701: scope list empty

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am implementing Push kit to my application, I have enabled the service from developer console and Huawei push SDK has been correctly integrated and I can see the app ID from agconnect-servicesjson to obtain the token. Which is 907135701:907135700

But however, when a Huawei mobile phone obtains the push token, the system crashes and the log is :

```
com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135700: get scope 
com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135701: scope list empty
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: How did you solve this problem ? If you share your solution, other people will benefit from your solution. Please share it

Comment: I have been trying with the old fingerprint, Once I updated it, problem is solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you please check whether the debug and release versions of your app use different signature certificate? If they are using different certificate, that might be the reason.

Comment: I'm Having the same issue. Does this means that it is mandatory to use the same certificate for debug and release versions?

Comment: Yes, I am using same certificate for both of them and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You must add your sha-256 fingerprint to the console.
It is not necessary to use the same certificate to debug and release. Only you need is add both debug and release certificates in AppGallery. On the screenshot below you can see that I've added two SHA-256 fingerprints:

[image]